# Is it good design to have one ObjectFactory interface and class that implements it

Tags: java, design-patterns

I'm wondering about the following class design.
I have one interface which is called ObjectFactory and one class that implements it which is called ObjectFactoryImpl. The class ObjectFactoryImpl has all methods for creating objects from package and to create instance of new object from that package ObjectFactoryImpl instance is required. Class ObjectFactoryImpl is also used internally in all classes that belong to package in wich it resides. Is it a good or bad design?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally it is a good practice to hide the implementation details behind interface, so you are on a "right" way.

However be consistent. Try to avoid direct usage of your implementation. You should always keep in mind that probably you will want to replace it by other one without changing your code (beyond factory).

Yet another comment is about the name that ends with `Impl`. Although I personally gave such names many times in my life, they say that suffix `Impl` is meaning-less. Well, it is implementation, so what? Try to give your classes self-explainable names. For example `SimpleObjectFactory`, `ConfigurableObjectFactory`, `XmlObjectFactory` etc.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I agree that name that ends with Impl is not a good one. I will change that to SimpleObjectFactory. Almost everywhere in my code I use ObjectFactory, the only place where it's not used is where I create concrete clas instance.

Answer (score 1):

Using an interface is a good practice in order to extend your code in the future. If you already created `ObjectFactory` I'd use it and not `ObjectFactoryImpl`. Perhaps in the future you'll have another implementation that you'd prefer to use.

Another option, which I sometimes do, is to define a concrete class `ObjectFactory` and use it. If I ever need to add another implementation for the factory I change the name of `ObjectFactory` to `ObjectFactoryImpl` and add another implementation. This way you don't have a lot of code changes because the most of the places using this class/interface stay the same.